# PylintSensor explodes on multi-module report

Tags: python, sonarqube, pylint

When running an analysis I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot analyse the
file'/home/user/project/package/module.py', details:
'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 302 is not a valid line for pointer.
File [moduleKey=com.project, relative=package/module.py,
basedir=/home/user/project] has 95 line(s)'
```

And that's correct, the file does have 95 lines. I checked the report generated by Pylint for that file (the last one in .sonar/pylint) and **there are messages for two modules**:

```
************* Module project.package.module
project/package/module.py:19: [C0301(line-too-long), ] Line too long (112/80)
project/package/module.py:1: [C0111(missing-docstring), ] Missing module docstring

************* Module django.contrib.admin.views.main
/home/user/.virtualenvs/project-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py:302: [W0201(attribute-defined-
outside-init), ChangeList.get_query_set] Attribute 'has_filters' defined outside __init__
```

So that's whence the 302nd line comes: the **file in which the super class is defined**. PyLint analyses the class in its entirely, for which it jumps to the virtualenv, **then reports messages for both files**. When the sensor processes that, it assumes there's only one file.

I think the sensor should be ignoring anything outside of the current file, since anything inside the project will be analysed eventually, and anything outside of the project will not be reported.

Is there a way to disable the analysis of dependencies in PyLint? (If so that's probably what Sonar should be doing, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the fix was simple enough: update Pylint.